# What is the best approach for using SSL if you are conterized Spring Boot application in docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, ssl, https, digital-ocean

I have a simple Spring Boot application. I have a docker image for it. I'm running that image in the container on an instance in some cloud(e.g. in a droplet in DigitalOcean). That droplet is connected to the specific domain name.
In what place it's better to implement SSL? Where should I put certificates? Is it necessary to use some 3rd party web server like `nginx` or additional `tomcat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest putting nginx in front to handle SSL as well as other common traffic chores (gzip'ing, CORS handling ...). It also allows you to isolate your application servers (spring boot) in their private network. Only the nginx service can be publicly exposed.

Eg:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  nginx:
    image:...
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - public
      - backend
  springboot:
    image: ...
    container_name: springboot
    networks:
      - backend
```